# Are all of these legitimate DocuSign authentication methods?

Tags: authentication, docusignapi, electronic-signature

I'm creating a SOAP interface for uploading Esignature requests to DocuSign. I need this interface to be prepared to request any authentication method that DocuSign supports. The SOAP API refers to several different types of authentication, for example in user profile AuthenticationHistory and AuthenticationStatus. For most, it is clear how to request these authentication types by setting the Recipient fields. But for a few of them, I see nothing to set in the Recipient, and no discussion anywhere in the documentation or on the internet about what to set to request those authentication methods, namely:

- AgeVerify
- OFAC
- STAN

How do I tell DocuSign that I want a signer authenticated by one of these methods?

Answer (score 0):

So, technically speaking, these DocuSign authentication methods *may* still be valid.  That being said though, I've never known of anyone to actually use them, and, based on the scarce availability of documentation related to these methods, I think it's entirely reasonable to assume that DocuSign is no longer promoting use of these authentication methods (that is, assuming they even still work in the current/latest version of DocuSign). Each of the 3 methods must be specifically enabled (by DocuSign) for a DocuSign account in order to be used, and each one incurs a $ cost per use.

- **STAN authentication** is specific to student lending, and relies on a student's FAFSA PIN number.
- **OFAC authentication** is supposed to validate whether a signer's name is on the Specially Designated Nationals List administered by the Office of Foreign Assets Control.
- **Age verification** is supposed to validate a signer's age is correct as entered.

I have no idea how these authentication methods actually work, beyond the basics I've listed above. If it were me building an interface to DocuSign, I probably wouldn't bother building support for these authentication methods. Even if they are still supported by the latest/current version of DocuSign, they're no longer being promoted in product documentation, and therefore I'd think the likelihood of anyone knowing about them, let alone actually using them, is slim to none.

Answer (score 0):

If it's listed in the [DocuSign SOAP API documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation) (or the REST documentation for that matter) then they should be available and ready for use.

Try using them and if get errors or can't use then contact your DocuSign account manager or post the issues here...

Comment: Yeah. The problem is that these are referenced as results in Status and History, but I see nothing in the API that would indicate how I might "try using them".